# jQuery not returning array/object but undefined in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, return

I Have a jQuery Post where I get variables. If I return the array I get undefined when the function is called. I have googled for a while not not understanding where the issue falls. Any Help Appreciated. I am normally a PHP Programmer. I'm assuming I am missing something here?

```
$(function() {

        $.getlanguage = function() {
                $.post("/", {
                        a: 'language'
                }).done(function(json) {
                        var lang =[];
                        lang = $.parseJSON(json);
                      console.log(lang) /// Works - Should return lang as array??
                        return lang;
                });
            }

            var language = [];
            language = $.getlanguage(); 
            console.log(language); /// Comes Back as Undefined

    });
```

Comment: <s>Asynchronous functions can not `return`.</s>

Comment: That's not how things work.

Comment: @callback Apt username...

Comment: @ROAL, of course they do. They just return before their work is complete.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm sorry, I've hit enter sooner than I actually wanted to. Yes, they return, but not in the way OP wants it to: Calling an async fn, assigning return value to a variable, returning in callback, having the return value from callback in the variable.